# How to move one li in ul to the far right? (see images)

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

[my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN463.png)
[devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp9Ar.png)

This is the components code, I am using shadcn:

```
const style = {
    marginRight: 'auto !important',
    alignSelf: 'end !important',
};

export default function AccountIcon() {
    return (
        <Avatar>
            <AvatarImage src="/account-circle.svg" alt="@DemoAccount" style={style} />
            <AvatarFallback>DE</AvatarFallback>
        </Avatar>
    );
}
```

```
const style = {
    width: '100vw',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
};

export default function Navbar() {
    return(
        <NavigationMenu style={style}>
            <NavigationMenuList style={style}>
                <NavigationMenuItem>
                    <NavigationMenuTrigger>Menu</NavigationMenuTrigger>
                    <NavigationMenuContent>
                        <NavigationMenuLink href='/'>Home</NavigationMenuLink><br></br>
                        <NavigationMenuLink href='/get-started'>Get Started</NavigationMenuLink><br></br>
                        <NavigationMenuLink href='/about'>About</NavigationMenuLink><br></br>
                        <NavigationMenuLink href='/settings'>Settings</NavigationMenuLink>
                    </NavigationMenuContent>
                </NavigationMenuItem>

                <NavigationMenuItem>
                    <NavigationMenuTrigger>Item Two</NavigationMenuTrigger>
                    <NavigationMenuContent>
                        <NavigationMenuLink>Link</NavigationMenuLink>
                    </NavigationMenuContent>
                </NavigationMenuItem>

                <AccountIcon />
            </NavigationMenuList>
        </NavigationMenu>
    );
}
```

I am trying to move the AccountIcon to the far right

I tried making the parent flexbox width to 100vw and justify content to flex start, and the AccountIcon margin right to auto and align self to end. I also tried making margin left to auto. Changing justifycontent to space between

I expect the AccountIcon to be on the far right but that is not happening.

Comment: Did you try float:right; when styling icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new style (style1) with the `justifyContent` of the `NavigationMenu` to `space-between` and then move the `AccountIcon` out of the `NavigationMenuList`.

```
const style1 = {
    width: '100vw',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
};
const style = {
    width: '100vw',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
};

export default function Navbar() {
    return(
        <NavigationMenu style={style1}>
            <NavigationMenuList style={style}>
                {/* Your code */}
            </NavigationMenuList>
            <AccountIcon />
        </NavigationMenu>
    );
}
```

This makes the `AccountIcon` to move to the right end of the screen.